# ObvservableCollection Adding Column I Didn't Ask For

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application that needs customer information retrieved from a database and displayed in a data grid.

Everything is working fine in the background, but when I add the customers to the ObservableCollection object, it is adding a variable to the table that I don't want.

This is where I use it:

```
private void button_DisplayInfo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // A collection of customer information
    ObservableCollection<Customer> customerCollection = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

    // Cycle through each customer in the customer list inside customerManager
    foreach (Customer eachCustomer in customerManager.CustomerList)
    {
        customerCollection.Add(new Customer
        {
            Name = eachCustomer.Name,
            CustomerID = eachCustomer.CustomerID,
            DateJoined = eachCustomer.DateJoined
        });
    }
    dataGrid_Main.ItemsSource = customerCollection;
}
```

The problem is that in the data grid, I am also getting a column that is a public bool property in the class that I did not specify to read at all, and it is putting a little checkbox instead of a value for it in the grid. Is there any way to prevent this, so that I can read (or at least output) only those three values from my Customer objects and not also the property?

Thanks!

P.S. The bool property is set in my constructor, if that means anything in regard to this.

Comment: You can either remove public property from the class or not AutoGenerateColumns.  AutoGenerateColumns is based on public properties (even if you don't give them a value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XAML, use the attribute AutoGenerateColumns="False" and list out the columns in DataGrid.Columns and specificy what they are bound do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the DataGrid autogenerate columns (set [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to false), and specify the columns manually.  This will give you complete control over which properties are displayed, and how they get displayed.